Windows 11, display resolution to 75%
coming for help as I am not sure that can be done, as I have not found a easy way to it
Scenario: I have a good sight, so my monitor is a 4K with 100% zoom, plenty od space for apps, and so on My secod display is a vertical 1080x1920 And "things are so big" in it ...
Current solution: I made a virtual 4K vertical monitor (either with a usbmmidd, or with a fake hdmi dong), and cast it with OBS to my second monitor, and configure it with 125% zoom
Unconfortable truth: ned to load manually OBS, sometimes crashes when swithting acccounts seems redundant
and all I want ti to simualate a higher resolution screen in my second screen
probably I should be buying a 1440x25600 (QHD) monitor and forget about the software solutions... but it is dificult to find a 21 inch with QHD resolution
what I would love that windows would let me scale teh screen to 75% , thats alll :-)
Any tip?
PD:

I have copy fron stackoverlof as I receive negatives due it is not a programing question
options like CRU, are not solutioon as I can not configure secondari screen resolution above native


If you have an AMD or Nvidia GPU, look into virtual super resolution. I know AMD has it, I think NVidia does too, but not sure. Basically, you get a larger resolution and the content is scaled down using anti aliassing. I use it on my 1080p TV to upscale it to 2560x1440p because my main monitor is 3440x1440, and by doing so, the desktop spaces are the same height. For my TV, I only use watching videos so the upscaling is really good for that, text can be a bit hard to read, but its also a TV. Should not be a problem for you. Note, this may not be present on old GPU's. Consider upgrading.
